# bash how to call command with saving quotes in parameter

Tags: bash

i have got the following code, and i i need to pass scheme parameters with spaces so i need to send it with quotes, but when i call my main command XCODE_RUN_COMMAND it's make my scheme in quotes but it add one more quotes.

```
[[ -n $XCODE_SCHEME ]] && XCODE_W_P_ARG="$XCODE_W_P_ARG -scheme \"${XCODE_SCHEME}\""
cd "${XCODE_PROJECT_DIRECTORY}"
XCODE_RUN_COMMAND="xcodebuild ${XCODE_W_P_ARG} -sdk ${XCODE_SDK} ${XCODE_CONFIG}"
$XCODE_RUN_COMMAND -showBuildSettings > xcodebuild.properties.prep || die "Fail got parameters from project parameter"
```

and i have got the following output and error:

```
xcodebuild -project ... -configuration Debug -scheme '"QVC' - 'QA.xcscheme"' -sdk iphoneos -xcconfig .../config.xcodeconfig -showBuildSettings
11:00:28 xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action '-'.
```

i was trying to do:

```
"$XCODE_RUN_COMMAND" -showBuildSettings > xcodebuild.properties.prep || die "Fail got parameters from project parameter"
```

but than all command in quotes and it doesn't work.

```
'xcodebuild -project .... -configuration Debug -scheme "QVC - QA.xcscheme" -sdk iphoneos -xcconfig .../config.xcodeconfig' -showBuildSettings
```

So how to call  $XCODE_RUN_COMMAND with saving quotes in scheme name?

i've made:

```
XCODE_W_P_ARG=( 'arg1' 'arg2' 'arg3' )
[[ -n $XCODE_SCHEME ]] && XCODE_W_P_ARG+=( -configuration  "$XCODE_CONFIGURATION" )
[[ -n $XCODE_SCHEME ]] && XCODE_W_P_ARG+=( -scheme "$XCODE_SCHEME" )
[[ -n $XCODE_SCHEME ]] && XCODE_W_P_ARG+=( -target "$XCODE_TARGET" )
cd "${XCODE_PROJECT_DIRECTORY}"
xcodebuild "${XCODE_W_P_ARG[@]}" -sdk "$XCODE_SDK" "$XCODE_CONFIG" - showBuildSettings > xcodebuild.properties.prep || die "Fail got parameters from  project parameter"
```

and output:

```
xcodebuild arg1 arg2 arg3 -configuration Debug -scheme 'QVC - QA.xcscheme' -target '' -sdk iphoneos '-xcconfig .../src/config.xcodeconfig' -showBuildSettings
11:52:55 xcodebuild: error: invalid option '-xcconfig .../src/config.xcodeconfig'
```

Comment: Recommended reading on the subject of using strings to store commands: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, the quotes around `$XCODE_SCHEME` are not working as you intended, so `"QVC`, `-` and `QA.xcscheme"` are being treated as three separate arguments. Use an array for your arguments instead:

```
XCODE_W_P_ARG=( 'arg1' 'arg2' 'arg3' ) # whatever was in there before the posted code
[[ -n $XCODE_SCHEME ]] && XCODE_W_P_ARG+=( -scheme "$XCODE_SCHEME" )
cd "$XCODE_PROJECT_DIRECTORY"
xcodebuild "${XCODE_W_P_ARG[@]}" -sdk "$XCODE_SDK" "$XCODE_CONFIG" -showBuildSettings > xcodebuild.properties.prep || die "Fail got parameters from project parameter"
```

Using the code in your latest update:

```
XCODE_W_P_ARG=()
XCODE_CONFIG=( -xcconfig .../src/config.xcodeconfig ) # "..." looks like a typo
if [[ -n $XCODE_SCHEME ]]; then
    XCODE_W_P_ARG+=( -configuration  "$XCODE_CONFIGURATION" )
    XCODE_W_P_ARG+=( -scheme "$XCODE_SCHEME" )
    XCODE_W_P_ARG+=( -target "$XCODE_TARGET" )
fi
cd "${XCODE_PROJECT_DIRECTORY}"
xcodebuild "${XCODE_W_P_ARG[@]}" -sdk "$XCODE_SDK" "${XCODE_CONFIG[@]}" - showBuildSettings > xcodebuild.properties.prep || die "Fail got parameters from  project parameter"
```

Comment: I can't read that at all - please edit your question to show what you mean.

Comment: you can see that xcconfig in quotes

Comment: I've updated my answer - it's the same issue as before. Use an array rather than a string.

Comment: @VladimirVoitekhovski note that the 'arg1' 'arg2' were just an example, you shouldn't use them in your code. Have you tried my latest suggestion?